# Show that the topological space $X$ is irreducible

Tags: general-topology

Let $f\colon X \to Y$ be a surjective open map between topological spaces. Show that if each set $f^{-1}({y})$ is irreducible , and if $Y$ is irreducible, then $X$ is irreducible.

**Def:** A topological space $X$ is irreducible if $X$ is nonempty and $X$ is not the union of two closed subsets different from $X$.(ofcourse there are many equivalent definition of irreducible topological space)

Because The fibres $f^{-1}(y)$ are just the equivalence classes under the relation $x\sim x'\leftrightarrow f(x)=f(x')$.Hence $X$ is union of disjoint equivalance classes,By using this I've proved this result by assuming  $f$ to be a **Closed**  map.But I'm unable in proving if $f$ is open map.Any ideas?

Comment: there is an alternate criterion for irreducibility i.e any two non empty open sets must intersect. You can try to solve this using this criterion

Comment: @happymath yeah I know this definition also.Can you say a bit more how to prove using this definition?

Comment: I have written an answer assuming you know that definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $X$ is not irreducible, and let $U$ and $V$ be disjoint non-empty open subsets of $X$; since $f$ is open, $f[U]$ and $f[V]$ are non-empty open subsets of $Y$. Suppose that $y\in f[U]\cap f[V]$, and consider the fibre $f^{-1}[\{y\}]$.

Comment: Its not a hint,its "almost" a solution :) Thank you,Best Regards,

Comment: @Arpit: It’s a very broad hint. `:-)` You’re welcome.

Comment: May I know why do you write $f[U]$ instead of $f(U)$?

Comment: @Arpit: The notation $f(U)$ makes it look as if $U$ is an element of the domain of $f$. Here, however, it’s a subset of that domain, and what we want is really $\{f(x):x\in U\}$; one common convention for distinguishing the two notions is to use square brackets for the image of a subset of the domain, so that $f[U]=\{f(x):x\in U\}$.

Comment: But I've seen even many good mathematicians also use $f(U)$ instead of $f[U]$.Anyways,thats just a matter of notation.once again,Thank you.Regards,

Comment: @Arpit: Yes, $f(U)$ is a very common abuse of notation. In many areas it’s unlikely to cause trouble; a lot of my background, however, is in set theory, where the distinction often does make a difference, so I’m in the habit of being careful that way.

Comment: Yeah I know,I've read your many answers on MSE,You'r really awesome Mathematician.I've just started my journey of learning Mathematics from minus infinity,I'm just learning some basic stuffs.Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Arpit: Your questions look like more than basic stuff to me! Anyway, you’re welcome, and thank *you*.

Answer (score 4):

Say that there exists open sets $U_1$ and $U_2$ which are non empty and do not intersect. Then take image $f(U_1)$ and $f(U_2)$ they are open and have an intersection. Say $y$ belongs to the intersection. Then $f^{-1}(y) \cap U_1$ and $f^{-1}(y) \cap U_2$ are two open sets in $f^{-1}(y)$ which do not intersect contradicting the irreducibility of $f^{-1}(y)$